# Connecting to Firebird on Windows with Python

Tags: python, firebird

I already broke my head, where is the problem.

```
import fdb
con = fdb.connect(host='localhost',
                      database='//soulu.fdb',
                      user='sysdba',
                      password='masterkey',
                      charset='WIN1251'
                      )
```

And I get this result. 
Already tried all variants: with charset utf8, win1251: use dsn, use separate host and database parameters. Run script under ubuntu for windows. Nothing helps.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ko-ov\Documents\Albatros\db for upload\loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    charset='WIN1251'
  File "C:\Users\ko-ov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 734, in connect
    "Error while connecting to database:")
  File "C:\Users\ko-ov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 560, in exception_from_status
    msglist.append('- ' + (msg.value).decode('utf_8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Which version of Firebird and which version of FDB?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks! Already found a root of problem:) Really, version 2.0.5 is very-very old and it was installed on my laptop (Just one rare and old programm uses this version by default and installs it in system). I updated to 2.5.x and all ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem (and @MarkRotteveel confirm it by his comment).
The solution for me is a **update to version 2.5.x from older 2.0.5**!

On the official page http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/devel-python-driver/ authors write, that versions 2.0 and later are supported, and theoretically all should works for 2.0.5 without any problem, but not in this case.

May be problem in combination of Win10, python 3.6 and firebird 2.0.5.

Comment: My guess is that some changes were made for Firebird 3 support that work fine for Firebird 2.5, but don't work for earlier versions under some circumstances (eg use of UTF-8 in the connection handshake was introduced as optional in 2.5, and is now - iirc - required for Firebird 3)

Comment: @konstov - register your problem in the tracker, so it would get fixed one way or another - http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&mode=hide&sorter/order=DESC&sorter/field=priority&resolution=-1&pid=10010&fixfor=-1